# rsync with X11-Forwarding does not set DISPLAY?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, manjaro, x11-forwarding

**Some context:**

- I have some services running on my Debian server, and from time to time I want to make a backup of the relevant data
- I have a `backup` directory on the server, which I update manually by stopping the services, copying the data into that directory (using `rsync -Payz --delete --recursive`, which preserves metadata and avoids unnecessary copies), then relaunching the services
- I want to have a copy of the `backup` directory on my laptop, and keep it updated
- To that end, I want to run something like `rsync -Payz --delete --recursive user@server:backup .`
- The main difficulty here is that many of the files have `root` as an owner and `rsync` isn't allowed to move them without `sudo` (the services run in containers, and those permissions make sense at the container level, but at the host level the system considers the host's `root` is the owner)
- To create the sever backup I can simply call `sudo rsync`, but for the copy on my laptop I have to tell `rsync` to run `sudo rsync` on the server and forward the password request to the client, which brings us to the current issue

**What I've done:**

I've followed the advice from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1167758), so the full command I'm running is

```
rsync -Payz --delete --recursive -e "ssh -X" --rsync-path="sudo -A rsync" user@server:backup .
```

- `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` is used to run `rsync` with `sudo` rights on the remote
- `--rsync-path="sudo -A rsync"` is used so that `sudo` relies on `ssh-askpass` to get the password
- `-e "ssh -X"` enables X11-Forwarding so that `ssh-askpass` can ask me to type the password on my laptop

**The issue**

- This used to on my old laptop (a MacBook), but doesn't on my new one (running a Manjaro distribution). Given that the linked post's comments say it's working on Ubuntu, I'm assuming I need to change something in my configuration, or maybe I'm missing a dependency or something, but I have no idea what or why
- The error I get is the following:

```
Error: Can't open display: 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: a password is required
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [Receiver=3.2.7]
```

- When I run the command with `-e "ssh -Xv"`, the following lines appear that seem to be the issue

```
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
debug1: Sending command: sudo -A rsync --server --sender -logDtprze.iLsfxCIvu . backup
Error: Can't open display: 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: a password is required
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
Transferred: sent 2176, received 2464 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9432.6, received 10681.1
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [Receiver=3.2.7]
```

so apparently when `rsync` runs `ssh -X` here, the `DISPLAY` variable is left unset

- If I run `ssh -X 'echo $DISPLAY` however, it does displays `localhost:10.0`, and running `ssh -X user@server 'sudo ls'` does ask me the password as expected (through a window titled "OpenSSH Authentification Passhrase Request")
- I believe that means that the problem is in the interaction between `ssh -X` and `rsync`, not the X11-Forwarding itself, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @meuh I'm running the rsync command manually from my client-side terminal (in which `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0.0`; from what I understand the variable is supposed to be set on the remote by the `ssh -X` command)

Comment: You might try ask the moderators to move your question to unix.stackexchange.com, or recreate it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only suggest you trace the environment being passed through rsync as follows. Add option `-n` to do no transfers, and use some `/tmp/dummy` file. Prefix the command with `strace` using option `-v` to see the environment during `execve()` calls, `-f` to follow children, and `-o log` to output to some log file.
For example,

```bash
DISPLAY=:0 strace -vf -o /tmp/log rsync -n -Payz  --delete --recursive \
 -e 'ssh -X' --rsync-path='sudo -A rsync' user@server:/tmp/dummy /tmp/dummy
```

Looking through the log file you should see something like

```C
5261  execve("/usr/bin/ssh", ["ssh", "-X", "-l", "user", "server", 
 "sudo -A rsync", "--server", "--sender", "-nlogDtprze.iLsfxC", ".",
 "/tmp/dummy"], ["DISPLAY=:0", "SHELL=/usr/bin/bash", ...] <unfinished ...>
```

(one long line).
Beware, you may need to ignore many execve's of `ssh` that are
attempted and fail as each directory in the current `PATH` is tried.
In this example output, 5261 is the process id.

The `execve()` system call of `/usr/bin/ssh` shows
the arguments to `ssh` in the first array `[...]`,
and the environment passed to the command in the second array `[..."DISPLAY=:0"...]`.
Ensure "DISPLAY=:0" is in this second array.

If it isn't, then look earlier in the file for the first `execve()` of `rsync` to see
if DISPLAY is in the env there.  You should find something like:

```C
5624  execve("/usr/bin/rsync", ["rsync", "-n", "-Payz", "--delete",
 "--recursive", "-e", "ssh -X", "--rsync-path=sudo -A rsync", 
 "user@server:/tmp/dummy", "/tmp/dummy"], [...,"DISPLAY=:0",...]) = 0
```

You can add a second `-f` to `strace` to get separate log files, one for
each process, rather than all intermixed.

If it is in the first `execve("/usr/bin/rsync"`, and not in the later
`execve("/usr/bin/ssh"`, that would indeed suggest that rsync has
deliberately removed it from the environment. Perhaps this is some sort of
new security feature?

To work round it, create your own shell script "ssh" in your `PATH` that
simply does

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0; exec /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
```

Comment: I ran the command, and `"DISPLAY=:0"` appears a single time in the log file, on the very first line (first `execve()`). What does it mean, and what can I do about it?

Comment: THANK YOU! That worked! Can you update your answer with what you told me in the comments, so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: I've revised the answer. Thank you for persisting enough to test the workaround. I imagine this problem is likely to be experienced by quite a few people if this really is a new feature of rsync, so I hope they find your post!